# Python pywin32/nssm can't start service

Tags: python, service, pywin32, nssm

My script/program consists of main.py; submethod1.py, submethod2.py in subdirectory; second subdirectory for temporary files; one txt file for logging I'm s struggling with running it as service for a week.

PyWin32 gives me  `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`. 
NSSM just writes this `Unexpected status SERVICE_STOPPED in response to START control` and nothing in stdout 
How to understand what is wrong with service? I can't debug it properly. 
It works standalone perfectly, I debugged it in IDE.

```
import configparser

from script.sql import *


def app():
    # reading .ini file
    print (os.getcwd())
    default_file = os.getcwd()+ r"/config.ini"
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read (default_file)
    path = config.get ("XLS", "dir")
    file_1 = path + "\\" + config.get ("XLS", "workbook1")
    file_2 = path + "\\" + config.get ("XLS", "workbook2")
    file_3 = path + "\\" + config.get ("XLS", "workbook3")
    usr = config.get ("SQL", "user")
    pwd = config.get ("SQL", "password")
    hst = config.get ("SQL", "host")
    db = config.get ("SQL", "database")
    pt = config.get ("SQL", "port")
    ssl_cert = config.get ("SQL", "ssl_cert")
    ssl_ca = config.get ("SQL", "ssl_ca")
    ssl_key = config.get ("SQL", "ssl_key")
    enc = config.get ("SQL", "encoding")
    sql_config = "mysql+pymysql://" + usr + ":" + pwd + "@" + hst + ":" + pt + "/" + db + "?" + ssl_cert + "&" + \
                 ssl_ca + "&" + ssl_key + "&" + enc

    if (os.path.isfile (file_1) == True or os.path.isfile (file_2) == True or os.path.isfile (file_3) == True):

        SQL.sqlconnect (sql_config)

        if (os.path.isfile (file_1) == True):

            XLS.xls_wrk (file_1)
            df_xls_1 = XLS.table_xls (file_1)
            df_sql_1 = SQL.table_sql (file_1, sql_config)

            if (df_sql_1.equals (df_xls_1) == False):
                try:
                    SQL.sql_import (file_1, sql_config)
                except:
                    SQL.table_trunc (file_1, sql_config)

        if (os.path.isfile (file_2) == True):
            XLS.xls_wrk (file_2)
            df_xls_2 = XLS.table_xls (file_2)
            df_sql_2 = SQL.table_sql (file_2, sql_config)

            if (df_sql_2.equals (df_xls_2) == False):
                try:
                    SQL.sql_import (file_2, sql_config)
                except:
                    SQL.table_trunc (file_2, sql_config)

        if (os.path.isfile (file_3) == True):
            XLS.xls_wrk (file_3)
            df_xls_3 = XLS.table_xls (file_3)
            df_sql_3 = SQL.table_sql (file_3, sql_config)

            if (df_sql_3.equals (df_xls_3) == False):
                try:
                    SQL.sql_import (file_3, sql_config)
                except:
                    SQL.table_trunc (file_3, sql_config)

        SQL.con_close (sql_config)

    else:
        with open (os.getcwd () + r"\PyXLSQL.log", "a+") as text_file:
            print (f"{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]} - Excel workbooks not found in dir {path}",
                   file=text_file)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

I used working templates like [all python windows service can not start{error 1053}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466053/all-python-windows-service-can-not-starterror-1053)

What can be wrong? There is a loop, or I can add one to check directory for any *xls files in RunSvc section. Anyway no useful debug info after trying running it as service.

UPDATE:

```
Debugging service PyTest - press Ctrl+C to stop.
Info 0x40001002 - The PyTest service has started.
Error 0xC0000003 - The instance's SvcRun() method failed

<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed

(null): (null)
```

With another template for running script as service.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar issue with NSSM. Make sure you are using the direct path for your file paths.

This line will work with NSSM:

> f_name = '//Bm-app1/bmcapps/logs/Hourly_Scripts.log'

This line will not work NSSM but will in the py file:

> f_name = 'W:\logs\Hourly_Scripts.log'

The first line is a direct path to another server where my file resides. The second line is a path to the same file but using my mapped drive.
When using the second line, NSSM will throw an error and not start the process. In another instance I've seen it kill my scheduled loop and the error will act more as a pass and moves directly to the next instance.

Comment: I know about `nssm`. My solution is different. I've changed code and compiled it to .exe with `Pyinstaller`. There are few answers about such solution. In my opinion, if you distribute it as standalone app it's the best solution, otherwise you have to install Python on users' machines or `nssm`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with NSSM, in my case the problem was due to the fact that I didn't set up the working directory correctly.

When creating a service out of a python script with the command: `nssm install '<SERVICE_NAME>' '<PYTHON_INTERPRETER_PATH>' '<SCRIPT_PATH>'` the working directory is set to the one containing the python executable.

To solve the issue I had to change the path to the one containing the script I wanted to run either with the command `nssm set <SERVICE_NAME> AppDirectory <SCRIPT_DIRECTORY>` or with the Edit-GUI `nssm edit <SERVICE_NAME>`